# Find nearest point of interest for each category in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, knn

I have 2 tables: `poi` and `categories` with below schema.

POI table:

| id | name | category | geog |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | poi-1 | cat-1 | point() |
| 2 | poi-2 | cat-1 | point() |
| 3 | poi-3 | cat-2 | point() |
| 4 | poi-4 | cat-3 | point() |
| .. | .. | .. | .. |

Number of records in table : about 1.8M

Categories table:

| id | category | cat_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat-1 | group-1 |
| 2 | cat-2 | group-1 |
| 3 | cat-3 | group-2 |
| 4 | cat-4 | group-3 |
| .. | ... | ... |
| 3000 | cat-3000 | group-78 |

Total Number of Categories: about 3000
Total Number of category types of categories: 80

**What I am trying to archive**

I would live to find nearest point of interest by distance from `poi` table for given latlong for each of the category type.

i.e.

for latlong: 53.960448, -1.092345, I would like to find nearest geometry which has categories (cat-1, cat-2, cat-3)

**what I have done so far**

```
SELECT up.id , up.name, up.category, up.geog <-> 'SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT ((-1.092345 53.960448))'::geography as distance
FROM poi up
WHERE up.category in (SELECT category FROM categories WHERE cat_type = 'group-1')
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1;
```

above query gives me nearest point for a latlong for only 1 group of categories. to get nearest point for all category types, right now I have to run this query for 80 times (total number of category groups).

Any guidance to optimize this / achieve required result in a better way?

**Result I am expecting**

What I am expecting is, nearest point of interest for each of the category type with distance.

| poi_id | category | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat-1 | 215 |
| 2 | cat-2 | 582 |
| 3 | cat-3 | 217 |
| 4 | cat-4 | 852 |
| .. | ... | ... |

#### Update 1

Solution provided by @dr_jts is able to provide required result. below is the query which is able to provide result in about 14-16 sec.

```
SELECT cat_type, id, latitude, longitude, dist 
FROM (SELECT dce.cat_type, array_agg(dce.category) as cats
FROM categories dce group by cat_type ) AS grps
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    (SELECT d.id, d.latitude, d.longitude, 
        geog <-> 'SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT ((-1.100818 53.956503))'::geography AS dist
      FROM poi d 
      WHERE d.category = ANY(grps.cats)
      ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1) AS d;
```

below is the sql `explain` result of the query:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=12.75..46877.63 rows=71 width=68) (actual time=24.431..14579.211 rows=77 loops=1)
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=12.34..13.22 rows=71 width=47) (actual time=1.138..1.713 rows=77 loops=1)
        Group Key: dce.cat_type
        Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 80kB
        ->  Seq Scan on categories dce  (cost=0.00..9.89 rows=489 width=31) (actual time=0.512..0.974 rows=516 loops=1)
  ->  Limit  (cost=0.41..660.03 rows=1 width=53) (actual time=189.314..189.315 rows=1 loops=77)
        ->  Index Scan using poi_geog_idx on poi d  (cost=0.41..5309278.81 rows=8049 width=53) (actual time=189.310..189.310 rows=1 loops=77)
              Order By: (geog <-> '0104000020E6100000010000000101000000EF91CD55F39CF1BF50C3B7B06EFA4A40'::geography)
              Filter: ((category)::text = ANY (((array_agg(dce.category)))::text[]))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 5682
Planning Time: 1.665 ms
Execution Time: 14580.360 ms
```

Comment: What do you expect the output table to look like? Is it one row per poi, and then 80 columns, one for each category group? Not very clear to me.

Comment: It's quite confusing to use a reserved word ("GROUP") as a field name, and somewhat ironic that you need a GROUP BY to address your issue.

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto I have updated the post with expected result.

Comment: @Vince I understand your concern. this is not the actual table. I have used a simplified sample table format for example. I have updated the post and replaced field name `group` with `cat_type` for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

When doing "nearest" queries it's most efficient to use the PostGIS [Nearest-Neighbour](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html) functionality.

To find the nearest neighbour in each group a separate (internal) query is required.  This can be described compactly in a single SQL statement by using `JOIN LATERAL` on the distinct group values:

```
WITH cat(category, grp) AS (VALUES
   (1, 'group-1')
  ,(2, 'group-1')
  ,(3, 'group-2')
  ,(4, 'group-2')
  ,(5, 'group-2')
  ,(6, 'group-3')
  ,(7, 'group-3')
),
data(id, category, geom) AS (VALUES
   (1, 1, 'POINT (0 0)'::geometry)
  ,(2, 2, 'POINT (1 1)'::geometry)
  ,(3, 3, 'POINT (0 0)'::geometry)
  ,(4, 4, 'POINT (1 1)'::geometry)
  ,(5, 5, 'POINT (2 2)'::geometry)
  ,(6, 6, 'POINT (0 0)'::geometry)
  ,(7, 7, 'POINT (1 1)'::geometry)
  ,(8, 7, 'POINT (2 2)'::geometry)
)
SELECT id, grp, dist, geom
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT grp FROM cat) AS grps
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    (SELECT d.id, d.category, d.geom,
          geom <-> ST_Point( 0.1, 0.1 ) AS dist
      FROM data d JOIN cat c ON d.category = c.category
      WHERE c.grp = grps.grp
      ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1) AS d;
```

Comment: You can also use `LEFT JOIN` to ensure all groups are included in result even if there is no points in that group.

Comment: The JOIN to the cat table can be avoided by using Posgres arrays:  `SELECT id, grp, dist, geom
12:21
FROM (SELECT grp, array_agg(category) as cats FROM cat GROUP BY grp) AS grps
12:21
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
12:21
(SELECT d.id, d.category, d.geom,
12:21
geom <-> ST_Point( 0.1, 0.1 ) AS dist
12:21
FROM data d
12:21
WHERE d.category = ANY (grps.cats)
12:21
ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1) AS d; `

Comment: Hi There, is surely is better and faster solution. but am not sure why it is still taking about 14-16 sec for the query. is there any why to optimize it further ?

Comment: Do you have appropriate indexes on the tables?

Comment: I have index on id and geometry for data/point of interest table and id on categories table.

Comment: You'll have to post the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see what's going on.  You are making 80 queries against 1.8 M records, so maybe that's just how long it takes.

Comment: I have added query and EXPLAIN ANALYZE result to the post. NESTED LOOP is taking majority of the time (>12 sec).

Comment: Querying for categories which don't have points might be slow. You could try querying to find only categories which do exist.

Comment: You could try running each category query separately, and see if a particular one is very slow.  Might give an idea of why performance is bad.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to normalize the data structure first.
In an existing structure, try:

```
SELECT p.id, p.category, y.distance
FROM 
  ( SELECT min(o.id) as id, c.cat_type, x.distance
    FROM 
      ( SELECT t.cat_type, min(i.geog <-> 'SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT ((-1.092345 53.960448))'::geography) as distance
        FROM poi i
          LEFT JOIN categories t on t.category = i.category
        GROUP BY t.cat_type
      ) x
      LEFT JOIN categories c on c.cat_type = x.cat_type 
      LEFT JOIN poi o on o.category = c.category and o.geog <-> 'SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT ((-1.092345 53.960448))'::geography = x.distance
    GROUP BY c.cat_type, x.distance
  ) y 
  LEFT JOIN poi p on p.id = y.id
```

I didn't test it on real data, but this query is at least first step to solve your problem.

Comment: That's great first step. I ran this query on my data and it is taking about 25-27 sec to return result. I am open to normalize the data structure, any suggestions ? also for optimizing this query further ?